# Binding rows of multiple data frames containing columns of class interval from lubridate package

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate, rbind

I have a list where each element is a data frame with the same column names, one of the columns is of class Interval (from lubridate package). I want to bind all the individual data frames in the list into a single data frame. Unfortunately using rbind and bind_rows coerces the interval column into a numeric and I receive the following warning.

Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not preserve their attributes

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
#Create sample list length 2 actually list length ~18,000
test <- list(BGC119AP01 = structure(list(participant_code = "BGC119AP01", 
    interval_1 = new("Interval", .Data = 34128000, start = structure(1479427200, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
    participant_code = "BGC119AP01", .rows = list(1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE)), 
    BGC119AP02 = structure(list(participant_code = "BGC119AP02", 
        interval_1 = new("Interval", .Data = 34128000, start = structure(1479427200, class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), groups = structure(list(
        participant_code = "BGC119AP02", .rows = list(1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE)))

#Attempt bind rows both ending in the above warning.
do.call(rbind, test)
do.call(bind_rows, test)
```

**OUTPUT**
Notice interval_1 has coerced to a double and lost its attributes

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   participant_code [2]
  participant_code interval_1
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 BGC119AP01         34128000
2 BGC119AP02         34128000
Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not preserve their attributes
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

This presumably is because columns of class interval are not atomic vectors. I am aware that I could solve this by retaining the original start and stop dates and then creating the interval column after binding the rows, but I would like a solution that allows me to bind all the individual data frames within the list whilst maintaining the integrity of the column of class interval and for the solution to be scalable to 18,000 rows. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you extend your `dput` to more than one row? It would help to see how attributes render for more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hint that when you do `do.call(rbind, test)` with `dplyr` loaded and get the warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

That `dplyr::bind_rows()` is actually being called and not `base::rbind()` and the interval attributes are dropped. This seems to occur when the objects are tibbles (`tbl` or `tbl_df` class).

You can avoid this by using `rbind.data.frame()` instead:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   participant_code [1]
  participant_code interval_1                    
* <chr>            <Interval>                    
1 BGC119AP01       2016-11-18 UTC--2017-12-18 UTC
2 BGC119AP02       2016-11-18 UTC--2017-12-18 UTC
```